# PID file in linux

Tags: linux, pid

i have a PID file holding processID say 1001 of a process(suppose squid). My question is, if i change the ownership of that pid file to nobody, will it change the ownership of that process(squid with pid 1001) to nobody?

Comment: No it wont. It might not even be the actual process that created the file, but the process that started the program in question. For example, lets say that an init script starts the Squid process, the init scripts gets the pid and writes the file, meaning the Squid process and the pid file are totally disconnected. And even if the Squid process created and wrote to the file, if changing owner of that file meant changing the owner of the process, that would mean that you could change owner of *any* process by changing owner of *any* file.

Comment: Do you mean the files in `/proc`?

Comment: yes, from a script i'm spawning the process and writing that spawned process's ID to PID file. but my question is, is it possible to change that spawned process ownership using that pid file?

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to change that spawned process ownership using that pid
>   file?

As Joachim Pileborg already explained (unfortunately only in a comment) that is definitely not possible. Ownership of file and process are completely independent.